# How can I set a table printing the residuals/fitted values of a regression to display multiple columns at once?

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table, formatting, r-markdown

I am trying to print a series of named numbers as part of an R Markdown html document (specifically, the fitted values and residuals of an `lm` regression. The list of numbers is very long, so I have the document set to paged tables using the option `df_print: paged`. However, I've noticed that there is a lot of unused blank space because there is only one column in addition to row names. I would like to try and set the table such that the displayed table wraps around and there are two or three series of columns displayed at once, sort of like what happens if I try to print a named number and there are two columns of named numbers displayed.

Here is an example that produces results similar to what I am trying to avoid using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
data(mtcars)
fit<-lm(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars)
data.frame(fit$residuals)
fit$residuals
```

Printing `fit$residuals` gets me closer to what I want in terms of space optimization, but it prints every single row and I cannot paginate the data (or at least, I do not know if it can be done).

Answer (score 0):

For two columns:

```
data(mtcars)
fit<-lm(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars)
df=data.frame(fit$residuals)
df1=cbind(df[1:16,], df[17:32,])
library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(df1, cgroup=c("Residuals 1:16", "Residuals 17:32"), n.cgroup=c(1,1), rnames=FALSE)
```

For three columns:

```
data(mtcars)
fit<-lm(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars)
df=data.frame(fit$residuals)
df1=cbind(df[1:11,], df[12:22,], df[23:33,])
htmlTable(df1, cgroup=c("Residuals 1:11", "Residuals 12:22", "Residuals 23:32"), n.cgroup=c(1,1,1), rnames=FALSE)
```